# Changing value in MySQL table gives syntax error

Tags: mysql

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but this is my first time using MySQL and I can't seem to get this to work:

I have this table:

```
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| policy_name                  | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| virus_lover                  | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| spam_lover                   | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unchecked_lover              | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| banned_files_lover           | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bad_header_lover             | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bypass_virus_checks          | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

and I would like to change virus_lover to NO

I have tried using

```
update policy set Null='N' where Field='virus_lover';
```

But this gives me a syntax error response. I have checked online and everyone seems to be suggesting this exact same command that doesn't seem to work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25

Comment: Your question is unclear. `UPDATE` is for updating the table's *data*. If you want to update its *schema*, you need `ALTER TABLE` and the correct syntax for it, which is similar to the `CREATE TABLE` commands you presumably used at one point.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to modify column attributes is with the `ALTER TABLE` command:

```
ALTER TABLE policy MODIFY virus_lover CHAR(1) NOT NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31189d69cb8a852bfa01dd63abbdf7db)

Comment: I downvoted you initially, but on re-reading the question, I think you've managed to read the OP's confusing question accurately.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, I think so. That output is from `show columns from policy`, it's not table data.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/null-values.html) is a reserved keyword and it's being used as a column name in the table, it must be quoted with backticks or brackets:

```
update policy set `Null`='N' where Field='virus_lover';
```

or

```
update policy set [Null]='N' where Field='virus_lover';
```

Changing the column name to a non-reserved keyword instead of `NULL` would make things easier as well.